# Boot error: AHCI controller unavailable!

Tags: boot, hardware

I hope I am asking this inside the correct community... I want to install Linux on my desktop PC, but even the most miniature `netinst` image fails to boot, no matter which image/distribution I take. (And I have tried a few flavors/images!)

---

I believe this must be some hardware incompatibility (my suspect is the storage controller), but of course, I cannot be sure of that. Oh, and by the way - Windows is working like a charm, so there is no hardware damage of some sort.

My hardware:

- CPU: Intel Core i5-3450 @ 3.1 GHz
- Mainboard: Asrock H77 Pro4 / MVP

When booting, the last message seen in the console is

> ```
> AHCI controller unavailable!
> ```

---

I already tried booting the kernel with the `noahci` option, doesn't change much - the kernel simply hangs after that message. Now, I know you cannot remotely guess the reason - I hope to figure out what options I have to find out where the problem is, for example, compile a debug kernel (how exactly would I do that?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Credit: The original idea came from the from [this conversation](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2411446&page=2):

This boot problem with the message:

> AHCI controller unavailable!

is related to the ASMedia ASM1061 chipset which simply does not work with CD / DVD / BluRay drives! The reason is, that it is not ATAPI compatible. I know it sounds weird, but trust me and read down.

Strangely, on older versions of the kernel (those of Ubuntu 14.04 for example), there was no problem with the boot.

---

There is a solution to this problem though:

Re-connect your CD / DVD / BluRay drive to another SATA port not linked to the ASMedia ASM1061, see the configuration of the ports in the manual for your motherboard.

---

Your motherboard indeed has this chipset, taken from [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H77%20Pro4MVP/index.asp):

- 2 x SATA3 6.0 Gb/s connectors by Intel® H77, support RAID (RAID 0, RAID 1, RAID 5, RAID 10, Intel® Rapid Storage and Intel® Smart Response Technology), NCQ, AHCI and Hot Plug functions
- 2 x SATA3 6.0 Gb/s connectors by ASMedia ASM1061, support NCQ, AHCI and Hot Plug functions

---

Actually, just re-plugging the CD / DVD / BluRay drive to the Intel chipset should work like a charm.

Note for orientation: SATA3_A2 -- note the **A** for ASMedia.